# XGBoost Explainer in R - How to enforce constraints to features Contribution?

Tags: r, constraints, modeling, xgboost

There are several R functions and packages to **estimate features contribution to the response variable as an output** of the XGBoost model.

For example there are the following:

- library(xgboostExplainer)

  - function: buildExplainer
- library(DALEX)

  - function: prediction_breakdown

Each of those functions return the contributions of each feature in the X matrix to the response variable. This is particularly useful with continuous target variables.

**Does anyone know how to constraint those contributions for example to be positive?**

Thanks